# Single sign-on between SharePoint (2010/2013) web applications using FBA?

Tags: single-sign-on

Say we have My Sites at

http://my.domain.com

and a project site under

http://projects.domain.com

User logs in to the project site, clicks his My Site link, and is asked for a username/password again.

How to enable Single Sign-On, so that user only needs to log in once? 
All the web applications sharing the same (aspnetdb) FBA user database.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solved it?

Comment: No. I've heard that Windows Server 2012 R2 might provide something here but not sure.